# Logistic Regression return a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, regression

I created a Logistic Regression algorithm with Numpy. The problem is that when I compute it, the weights are a matrix instead of a vector, so it soesn't throw any errors, but when I try to predict some input, instead of the value, I get a matrix (the input*weights matrix).

I now the weights sould be a scalar, but somehow adding a new dimension fixes lots of errors that I was getting, if you can take a look at the code and have any idea, that'd be great.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
dataset = dataset.dropna(axis=0)

y = np.array(dataset['Survived']).reshape(-1,1)
X = np.array(dataset['Age']).reshape(-1,1)

class LogisticRegression:
    def __init__(self, lr=0.01, num_iter=100000, fit_intercept=False, verbose=True):
        self.lr = lr
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.fit_intercept = fit_intercept
        self.verbose = verbose
    
    def add_intercept(self, X):
        intercept = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1))
        return intercept, np.concatenate((intercept, X), axis=1)
    
    def __sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
        
    def __loss(self, h, y):
        return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        if self.fit_intercept:
            _,X = self.add_intercept(X)
        
        # weights initialization
        # Here, using np.zeros(X.shape[1]) will be correct but doesn't seem to work (different shapes)
        self.theta = np.zeros([X.shape[1], X.shape[0]])
        
        for i in range(self.num_iter):
            z = np.dot(X, self.theta)
            h = self.__sigmoid(z)
            gradient = np.dot(X.T, (h - y)) / y.size
            self.theta -= self.lr * gradient
            
            if(self.verbose == True and i % 10000 == 0):
                z = np.dot(X, self.theta)
                h = self.__sigmoid(z)
                print(f'loss: {self.__loss(h, y)} \t')
    
    def predict_prob(self, X):
        if self.fit_intercept:
            _,X = self.add_intercept(X)
    
        return self.__sigmoid(np.dot(X, self.theta))
    
    def predict(self, X, threshold):
        return self.predict_prob(X) >= threshold

model = LogisticRegression(lr=0.1, num_iter=3000)
model.fit(X, y)

pred = model.predict(X[12], y[12])

intercept,_ = model.add_intercept(X)
yhat = intercept + model.theta * X
# yhat is the regression line from the model
```

Comment: Can you upload a link to your 'dataset.csv' file so that your codes and results can be reproduced?

Comment: Your use of `matrix` and `vector` may be vague.  In `numpy` we normally talk about dimensions - 1d, 2d etc.  Arrays with a shape (n,), (1,n) and (n,1) can all have the same values, but depending on the application may behave differently.

Comment: `y = np.array(dataset['Survived']).reshape(-1,1)`.  A `pandas` dataframe is 2d, and column is a `Series`, 1d.  So `dataset['Survived'].to_numpy()` is a 1d array, shape (n,).  The reshape makes it 2d (n,1) (in other languages a column vector).  Machine-learning often uses a 2 or 3d convention, (batches, samples, features).  `dataset[['Survived']].to_numpy()` is another way of getting that column vector, since column selection with a list produces a dataframe (as opposed to a Series).

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your response, I made the changes and it seems to work well. My doubt si with the predicted value I get, because the y column is a scalar value (either 0 or 1) I supose that I should receive a scalar or even a matrix of two elements with the probability of each outcome. But instead I get a huge matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, with `X, y` being the following:

```
X = np.arange(10)
y = 4 * X + np.random.normal(size=X.shape)
```

It seems to run fine (i.e no errors). Consider Skipping the reshaping that you currently do, unless you want to handle higher dimensions later.

Comment: Yes, I mean, I don't get errors too, the only issue I have is that the predicted values is a matrix of the size of the weights matrix instead of a scalar (which is the y value that is being predicted), BTW thanks for your response